# Popping to view controller, how do I call a method in the view controller I am popping to?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based app and I am trying to pop back to to a certain view controller and it works fine, however I am trying to call a method (account) in the view controller I am popping to. The method gets called however when I push to the view controller ,but doesn't get call when I pop to it. What can I do to call the method when I pop to the view controller?

CurrentViewController.m

```
 -(void)viewControllerPop{
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [viewController account];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Three answers:

1 Consider not doing it.  The view controller you're popping to should
    observe a change in the model (affected by the pushed vc) and change
    it's views accordingly in viewWillAppear.

2 Make the the view controller you're popping to a delegate of the pushed vc, define a protocol message that tells the delegate about the condition so it can change it's views.

3 The worst answer, IMO, but you can inspect the navigation controller's view controller stack and get a pointer to the vc that pushed you.  (The code you posted is mixed up, it won't do any good to allocate a new vc, change one of it's views and then pop to the one that pushed you.  That new `viewController` you're allocating lives for only an instant, and is immediately discarded).

```
-(void)viewControllerPop {
    NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    NSUInteger count = viewControllers.count;
    ViewController *vcUnderMe = viewControllers[count-1];  // this top one is at count-1

    // I disagree with this in principal, but here's what you're asking
    [vcUnderMe account];         // not sure what this method does... not named well
    vcUnderMe.accountLabel.hidden=NO;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` on UINavigationControllerDelegate to send a message rather than sorting through the `viewControllers` property?

Comment: Yes, so long as the delegate is aware that it will be fired when any vc is about to be pushed or popped (including ones pushed by the pushed vc).